# How to use react route with href

Tags: reactjs, react-router

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83aJb.png)

I tried this way and the problem is as follows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not linking it properly.

Try this:

```
<a href=`page/${person.id}` classaName="scam-title_link"></a>
```

Or use the Link tag provide by react-router-dom:

```
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

<Link to=`page/${person.id}`>WHATEVER YOU WANT TO ADD HERE!</Link>
```

Check this [reference](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link) for further understanding.

Comment: More accurately is:
    <Link to={`/scamer/${person.id}`}>
        {person.name}
    </Link>

Comment: Thanks for correcting. You still need to add ` `.